# Stack Overflow Careers - Cannot remove 'willing to relocate' location

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

When editing my profile in Stack Overflow Careers.
Some time ago, I wrote that I am willing to relocate into UK, Germany and US.
Meanwhile things have changed, and I do not wish to move to Germany or US anymore.
I found that I cannot remove the two items from the list: that is, the interface allows me to do that but when I choose 'Save' the page refreshes without the changes taking place.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for spotting this; I've just pushed a build that fixes it.

Comment: shiiiiny diaamond... :)